# Set Controls with arbitrary positions on CTabItem

Tags: swt, setbounds, ctabitem

I am new to SWT, and I need to set the controls positions arbitrary on CTabItem.

I've used the following code, but it seems that it had no positioning effect, it just add the component to (0, 0)

```
Label userName = new Label(folder, SWT.NONE);
userName.setText("username");
userName.setBounds(10, 200, 200, 50);
item.setControl(userName);
```

Comment: Do you mean GWT or SWT? Because the `Label` class you are using looks to be the `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label` class and not the `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label` class, which would make sense for GWT.

Comment: it is SWT, I have modified it.

Comment: You need to remove the gwt tag from your question and tag it swt -- otherwise the right people won't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set a LayoutManager to `folder`, e.g.:

```
folder.setLayout(new GridLayout());
```

If you wish to give the control a certain dimensions, consider giving it LayoutData, e.g.:

```
GridData gd = new GridData();
gd.height = 50;
userName.setLayoutData(gd);
```

I'm not sure what `item` is in your example, but it doesn't seem to be necessary.